# Python: Extract min from a subgroup and max from another subgroup

Tags: python

I have a primary group labeled 'key', sub-group labeled 'Country' and a 'Cost' values. For each primary group 'key', I first want to extract the min Cost then get the max 'Cost' within the other sub-groups, i.e., get the max 'Cost' from within the remaining countries ignoring all entries of the country from which the min is taken from (max cost has to be one single value not max cost each of the remaining countries).

My Data looks like

```
key     COUNTRY       COST  
X1      A1             1.2  
X1      A1             1.5  
X1      A2             0.8  
X1      A2             0.9  
X1      A3             2.1  
X1      A3             0.7  
X1      A3             1.9  
X2      A1             0.4  
X2      A3             2.2  
X2      A3             1.0
```

My code is a 'for-loop' and it is not efficient. Please suggest a better way of doing this. Below is my code.

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame()

grouping = list(data.groupby('key',as_index=False).groups.keys())

for group in grouping:

    df_group = data[data['key']==group]
    country_count = df_group.COUNTRY.nunique()

    if country_count > 1:
        group_min_cost = df_group.loc[df_group['COST'].idxmin()]

        drop_index = df_group[df_group['COUNTRY'] == group_min_cost.COUNTRY].index
        df_group = df_group.drop(drop_index)

        group_max_cost = df_group.loc[df_group['COST'].idxmax()]

        summary = {'key': group,
                   'Country_Min': group_min_cost.COUNTRY,
                   'Country_Max': group_max_cost.COUNTRY,
                   'Cost_Min': group_min_cost.COST,
                   'Cost_Max': group_max_cost.COST}

        df_out = df_out.append(summary, ignore_index=True)
```

The output that I am looking for is

```
key    Country_Min    Cost_Min  Country_Max    Cost_Max  
X1      A3             0.7       A1             1.5   
X2      A1             0.4       A3             2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to use loops for this type of operation.  There's a few ways to get this without row-level looping.  Here's one:

```
countries = pd.unique(df['COUNTRY'])

for country in countries:
    idx = df['COUNTRY'] == country
    min_cost = min(df.loc[idx, 'COST'])
    max_cost = max(df.loc[idx, 'COST'])
    print('min/max cost for {0}: {1}, {2}'.format(country, min_cost, max_cost))
min/max cost for A1: 0.4, 1.5
min/max cost for A2: 0.8, 0.9
min/max cost for A3: 0.7, 2.2
```

Even simpler is to use an aggregation function, which returns a dataframe with the min cost values:

```
projection = {'COST': ['min', 'max']}

df_min_cost = df.groupby(by='COUNTRY').agg(projection)

df_min_cost
```

Returning:

```
    COST
min max
COUNTRY     
A1  0.4 1.5
A2  0.8 0.9
A3  0.7 2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For first half of your question you can use this construction:

`data.iloc[data.groupby(['key'])['cost'].idxmin().values]`

where `data` is your dataframe, but still don't have idea about how to mask with this dataframe without loop.